# match string pattern in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that can contain links:

```
<a href="http://site1.com/">Hello</a> <a href="http://site2.com/">Hello2</a>
<a href="http://site3.com">Hello3</a> ...
```

How can I extract the text (not the link) of all html  tags "Hello", "Hello2", "Hello3" ... ? I'm thinking of a list that should contain all texts.

Comment: you want to look into the `BeautifulSoup` library

Comment: Never use regex for parsing! Never!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/):

```
import lxml.html as LH

content = '''
<a href="http://site1.com/">Hello</a> <a href="http://site2.com/">Hello2</a>
<a href="http://site3.com">Hello3</a>
<a href="/">go <b>home</b>, dude!</a>
'''

doc = LH.fromstring(content)
texts = [elt.text_content() for elt in doc.xpath('//a')]
print(texts)
```

yields

```
['Hello', 'Hello2', 'Hello3', 'go home, dude!']
```

Comment: Please don't use `/text()`, it's a [code smell](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell). In particular, it will do funny things on links like `<a href="/">go <b>home</b>, dude!</a>`

Comment: I'd do `//a/string()`. Is your version equivalent?

Comment: I just tried that; for some reason lxml raises `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression`.

Comment: @larsmans: But to answer your question, yes, [text_content()](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) will return all the text between `<a>` and `</a>` with no markup.

Comment: `string()` is probably XPath 2.0, LXML only supports 1.0. +1 for a clean solution.